# Better Way of Passing Parameter To 2nd Page Through MVVM Light NavigationTo

Tags: c#, mvvm-light, uwp-xaml

I'm using **MVVM Light**, and currently I have 2 UWP Pages, which I registered in a subclass of **INavigationService**. like below:

```
var nav = new CustNavigationService();
nav.Configure("FirstPage", typeof(FirstPage));
nav.Configure("SecondPage", typeof(SecondPage));
SimpleIoc.Default.Register<ICustNavigationService>(() => nav);
```

and I want to send parameter from the 1st to the 2nd using navigation object like below:

```
// Inside 1st Page code:
var args = "Hello From Page 1";
var nav = SimpleIoc.Default.GetInstance<ICustNavigationService>();
nav.NavigateTo("SecondPage", args);
```

Is there anyway I can get passed arguments from the 1st page in 2nd page **ViewModel**, without **overriding OnNavigatedTo** at 2nd page **codebehind** ?

I tried to find elegant way without using **codebehind**. And without using **Messaging** (which I found it not so elegant).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In general, for navigating with parameter in the view model within **MVVM Light**, you could use `NavigationService`. But mvvm light does not provide `OnNavigatedToAsync` such method in the `ViewModelBase` base class. So, you need receive parameter from codebehind. And other way is using `Messaging`.

I recommend you use [`Template10`](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/wiki). It is relatively more comprehensive. And it provides [`OnNavigatedToAsync`](https://github.com/Windows-XAML/Template10/blob/master/Source/Prism.Windows/Mvvm/ViewModelBase.cs#L23) visual method that use to get navigation parameter in the view mode.

```
public override async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> suspensionState)
{
    Value = (suspensionState.ContainsKey(nameof(Value))) ? suspensionState[nameof(Value)]?.ToString() : parameter?.ToString();
    await Task.CompletedTask;
}
```